# How can I create custom HTTP body

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, json, httprequest

I'm building aura app and I have trouble sending custom body to HTTP callout.
I have problem constructing custom body for HTTP API callout in Apex. I want to get data from third party system (piwik.pro) and I need to send them the website_id, which columns I want to fetch, dateFrom-dateTo and optionally if I want to filter fetched data, I need to send them the filters.

I have successfully fetched session data from Postman using this JSON body (from their official HTTP API page) https://prnt.sc/xUf_GoXvTC79:

```
{
"website_id": "47cd13e8-42ac-4787-9431-53df4db449d8",
"columns": [
    {
    "column_id": "session_total_page_views"
    },
    {
    "column_id": "device_type"
    }
],
"date_from": "2020-01-10",
"date_to": "2020-02-10",
"filters": {
    "operator": "and",
    "conditions": [
    {
        "column_id": "browser_name",
        "condition": {
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": "FF"
        }
    }
    ]
},
"offset": 0,
"limit": 100,
"format": "json"
}
```

First is webSiteId and user chooses that through picklist on the frontend, **next is what is confusing me**. There is list of columns that user can choose from to fetch data about (in this example there're 2 objects but that is a variable - sometimes 1 sometimes 10). The dates (date_from, date_to) also need to be set as a variables so that is not hardcoded.

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried using http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to generate my class as I've read multiple questions that suggested that but I still don't understand how can I use that to create my request body.

Also, I tried to hardcode

```
    String json = '{'+
            '  \"website_id\": \"47cd13e8-42ac-4787-9431-53df4db449d8\",'+
            '  \"columns\": ['+
            '    {'+
            '      \"column_id\": \"session_total_page_views\"'+
            '    },'+
            '    {'+
            '      \"column_id\": \"device_type\"'+
            '    }'+
            '  ],'+
            '  \"date_from\": \"2020-01-10\",'+
            '  \"date_to\": \"2020-02-10\",'+
            '  \"filters\": {'+
            '    \"operator\": \"and\",'+
            '    \"conditions\": ['+
            '      {'+
            '        \"column_id\": \"browser_name\",'+
            '        \"condition\": {'+
            '          \"operator\": \"eq\",'+
            '          \"value\": \"FF\"'+
            '        }'+
            '      }'+
            '    ]'+
            '  },'+
            '  \"offset\": 0,'+
            '  \"limit\": 100,'+
            '  \"format\": \"json\"'+
            '}'; 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(json);
```

But it doesn't work for me, because I'm hardcoding the number of columns, the columns, the dateFrom, dateTo, filter... Virtually everything.

So, what I'm asking is - how can I code this so I don't hardcode number of columns, columns and let the user choose how many she/he wants and choose the dateFrom, dateTo and serialize all the and send the String to req.setBody(String);

**UPDATE 08/24/2022**

I got method that has args that I'm sending to it from aura components attributes.

```
//================================ FECHES SESSION DATA ========================================
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String fetchSessions (String webSiteId, List<String> stringColumns, String date_from, String date_to, Integer offset, String format, String token){
        try{
            // CUSTOM ENDPOINT
            String customEndpoint = webSiteId + '/api/analytics/v1/sessions/';
            // CUSTOM BODY 
            Data data = new Data();
            data.website_id = webSiteId;
            // data.columns = columns;
            data.date_from = date_From;
            data.date_to = date_to;
            data.offset = offset;
            data.format = format;
            // MAKE THE API CALL
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
            req.setEndpoint(customEndpoint);
            req.setBody(JSON.serialize(data));
            
            Http h = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
            
            String strResponse = res.getBody();
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200){ 
                Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            }
            else {
                return res.getStatus(); //return the responses StatusCode message
            }
            return null; //return the data
        }
        catch (exception ex){
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
            return ex.getMessage(); //return the exception
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate an object of type Data but I can't understand how can I set data.columns when I have List that I accept as an argument and I cannot declare **List name = new List();** because I have the Data class with all its sub-classes in separate apxc class. Moreover I tried to copy-paste the Data class into my main class and It gave me the error that I cannot have classes and sub-classes and methods in one class.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your attempt with json2apex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can make this dynamic by defining class structures, i.e.:

```java
public class Data {
    public String website_id;
    public List<Column> columns;
    public String date_from;
    public String date_to;
    public Integer offset;
    public String format;
    public Filter filters;

    public class Column {
        public String column_id;
    }

    public class Filter {
        public String operator;
        public List<Condition> conditions;
    }

    public class Condition {
        public String column_id;
        public List<Operation> conditions;
    }
    
    public class Operation {
        public String operator;
        public String value;
    }
}
```

Then, we can deserialize the payload into this structure like so:

```java
Data responseData = (Data) JSON.deserialize(payload, Data.class);
```

Conversely, you can instantiate your Data object, assign its properties and then serialize it into JSON for your HTTP request's body:

```java
Data d = new Data();
d.website_id = 'someid';
// assign other properties...

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(d));
```

For the column attribute, you'd need to iterate over the string array (`myColumnStringList` in this example) and initialize column objects, i.e.:

```java
List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();
for (String column_id : myColumnStringList) {
    Column c = new Column();
    c.column_id = column_id;
    columns.add(c);
}
```

Comment: How can I send the body to HTTP POST method request? I understand that setBody accepts only string argument and I need to json.serialize(payload).

Comment: @Stojcheski - you would instantiate the object and assign whatever values needed - I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: One more question. I need to set the value of the List<Column> columns to my entry List<String> columns and I get illegal assignment from List to List which is to be expected. So, how do I make the method accept List<Column>?

Comment: The JSON example provided shows that `columns` is not an array of Strings, but an array of Objects - this is why we defined an inner class called Column. To convert from your List<String> variable, you may need to iterate over its contents and instantiate column objects. I've provided an example above in my answer.

Comment: Hey @JesseWheeler I've updated my question with my method and I still cannot solve this problem of how can I send data.columns in my method. Can you provide further explanation on your thought process. I'm sorry for still bothering you about this. Thank you.